# Excel Formula, get the previous wednesday date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following formula,

`=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-2)`

Which gets me Jan 30th.

Is there anyway I can get Jan 30th without putting the -2 in this formula? I want he formula to always get the previous Wednesdays date, but I manually just subtract the todays workday to get the previous Wednesday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For reference, the [previously accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1401040/43356) wrongly outputs future date for some scenarios

This formula outputs the **previous Wednesday**.

```
=TODAY()-MOD(WEEKDAY(TODAY())+2,7)-1
```

If today is Wednesday, it outputs the previous Wednesday as well.

`MOD(..., 7)` always returns value from 0 to 6.

So, `-MOD(...)-1` always subtracts a value of 1 to 7 (days) from `TODAY()`.

(You can adjust the value `+2` in the formula to get different weekdays)

---

Example:

- Today is `2019-2-25 (Mon)`, outputs `2019-2-20 (Wed)`
- Today is `2019-2-26 (Tue)`, outputs `2019-2-20 (Wed)`
- Today is `2019-2-27 (Wed)`, outputs `2019-2-20 (Wed)`
- Today is `2019-2-28 (Thu)`, outputs `2019-2-27 (Wed)`

Comment: nice! this is more what I want. is there anyway to use current  wednesday instead of reverting to previous?

Comment: yes, it will be even simpler. here you are: `=TODAY()-MOD(WEEKDAY(TODAY())+3,7)`. the `MOD(...)` always return value from 0 to 6, so you can get result ranging from [today-6days] to [today].

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
=TODAY() - MOD(TODAY(), 7) + 4
```

Which means get first day of current week (Saturday), then add 4 = Wednesday, (optionally -7 for the previous week).

If you want the previous week (if you are still in Sunday or Monday), then use `if` for `MOD(TODAY(), 7)`

Comment: I'm having trouble following the explanation. Why is the first day of the current week a Saturday (as opposed to Monday or Sunday depending on what calendar system you use)? If you add 4 to a Saturday I can see that you get Wednesday, but why would -7 get you to the previous Wednesday? It seems to me that Saturday - 7 = Saturday. Note: I'm not questioning the formula, but merely the explanation that goes with it.

Comment: @JonBentley the -7 is meant to be appended to the shown formula, not subsituted in for the +4. As to why MOD(TODAY(),7) produces this very helpful result, I'm also curious.

Comment: @AlexM Dates in excel are like an integer. Today, for example, is 43497. If you divide it by 7 using the MOD formula, will always return 6 if a day is Friday. This works because the very first day excel accepts. By dividing by 7, you guarantee that you will always get a number from 0-6 (Because 7 / 7 = 1, which returns nothing). 8/7 returns 1 for everyone and 1 not divided.

Comment: So now you went to the Saturday of this week(considering Saturday would be the first day), then the +4 corrects it to Wednesday

Comment: @Moacir thanks for the info; I suppose this is most likely fodder for a separate question, but I find it very curious (which just makes it fit with everything else about the way Excel works with dates in my experience, I guess) that though TODAY() returns the date 'formatted as a date' you're still able to use numerical operations against the underlying date value. Adding to my confusion, when I entered =MOD(TODAY(),7) into an empty cell, to test this behavior, it output 1/6/1900 - which I now understand means it returned the numeral 6 (as your formula expects), only formatted as a date.

Comment: You can then format it to number and it will not try to format as date again :)

Comment: The formula (`=TODAY()-MOD(TODAY(),7)+4`) is wrong. If today is `2019-2-25`, and the formula outputs `2019-2-27` which is a future date.